# get user by sanctum token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I have a token like `1|bTNlKViqCkCsOJOXWbtNASDKF7SyHwzHOPLNH` and I wanna find the user by this token.

note: I can not use `auth()->user` in a specific controller. thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will convert a personal token and return the user:

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken;

$bearerToken = "1|bTNlKViqCkCsOJOXWbtNASDKF7SyHwzHOPLNH";

$token = PersonalAccessToken::findToken($bearerToken);

if (!$token) {
    dd("Error: Token not found");
}

$user = $token->tokenable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel sanctum use a polymorphic relationship. So, you need to [read the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-retrieving-the-relationship) about how to retrieve data in that relation. It's something like this.

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken;

$token = PersonalAccessToken::where(...);
$user = $token->tokenable;
```