# In laravel passport, how to get the user model from given access_token?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-passport

I have an access_token string. I want to know who own that access_token, which user related with that access token. Something like

```
$user = Auth::guard('api')->getUserModel('aeZakmihEsoyAmAlLcaRsGoBoOm123JumpjetmonSterMash===');
```

How to do that?

Thanks

Comment: As per documentation you must use authorization header and middleware https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#protecting-routes

Another way - get it from database. Check `HasApiTokens` trait that as default connected inside `User` - there are `tokens()` relation

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67664192/8016720

Comment: If you have configured passport properly and I assume your route is in 'api' authguard. You should be able to retrieve user by using `$request->user()`